# Chaining a sequence of things that are either owned or referenced

Tags: rust, lifetime

I'm attempting to have a trait for things that can either simply contain other things, or create them on demand, given a thing's name. Those contained things should in turn be able to do the same, creating a hierarchy of sorts. Here's a minimal code:

```
use std::ops::Deref;

pub enum BoxOrRef<'a, T: ?Sized + 'a> {
    Boxed(Box<T>),
    Ref(&'a T),
}

impl<'a, T: ?Sized + 'a> Deref for BoxOrRef<'a, T> {
    type Target = T;
    fn deref(&self) -> &T {
        match self {
            BoxOrRef::Boxed(b) => &b,
            BoxOrRef::Ref(r) => r,
        }
    }
}

pub trait Elem {
    fn get_subelem<'a, 'b>(&'a self, name: &'b str) -> Option<BoxOrRef<'a, dyn Elem>>;
}

pub trait Table {
    fn get_elem<'a, 'b>(&'a self, name: &'b str) -> Option<BoxOrRef<'a, dyn Elem>>;
}

fn resolve_name<'a, T: Table + ?Sized>(
    table: &'a T,
    name: &[String],
) -> Option<BoxOrRef<'a, dyn Elem>> {
    let mut segments = name.iter();
    if let Some(first_segment) = segments.next() {
        segments.fold(table.get_elem(&first_segment), |res, next| {
            res.and_then(|elem| elem.get_subelem(next))
        })
    } else {
        None
    }
}
```

The lifetime checker however, is not satisfied by this:

```
error[E0597]: `elem` does not live long enough
  --> src/lib.rs:33:33
   |
33 |             res.and_then(|elem| elem.get_subelem(next))
   |                                 ^^^^                 - borrowed value only lives until here
   |                                 |
   |                                 borrowed value does not live long enough
   |
note: borrowed value must be valid for the lifetime 'a as defined on the function body at 26:17...
  --> src/lib.rs:26:17
   |
26 | fn resolve_name<'a, T: Table + ?Sized>(
   |                 ^^
```

I need to somehow extend lifetimes of the intermediate `res`'s. I guess I could put them in a struct and tweak the return type of `resolve_name` to return it along with the final element, but that strikes me as rather clumsy way of doing it. Is there a better solution?

Comment: I'm not sure how helpful this is, but the code can be simplified further. https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=d472c89829c2c0e5286982486d1746f7&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015 I don't yet understand why this works with an `&` ref but not with the custom `Ref` wrapper.

Comment: @PeterHall The problem is with `deref` (or any kind of accessor method) not with `Ref` vs `&`: https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=6702c035798ab0335c5199e7aad3cfc6&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015.  If you comment out the `()` in my example, you will get the same error. If you comment out `()` and `'a` the error is gone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return value of `get_subelem` can't outlive the `&self` borrow you used to call it, because the signature of `get_subelem` says so explicitly:

```
fn get_subelem<'a, 'b>(&'a self, name: &'b str) -> Option<BoxOrRef<'a, dyn Elem>>;
//                      ^^                                         ^^
```

In order to get a `BoxOrRef<'a, _>`, you have to borrow `self` for the lifetime `'a`. In the caller, `elem` can't outlive the closure it belongs to, and `get_subelem` borrows `elem`, so it can't return a value that can escape that closure either.

You're trying to do something that is unsafe, and the compiler is right to stop you. In theory, `table.get_elem` could return a `Boxed` value, and `elem.get_subelem` could return an internal reference, and then the `Box` would be dropped when the closure returns, invalidating the reference.

Presumably that doesn't actually happen, so you have to tell the compiler that. One way is to decouple `&self` from `BoxOrRef<'a, _>`:

```
pub trait Elem<'a> {
    fn get_subelem(&self, name: &str) -> Option<BoxOrRef<'a, dyn Elem<'a>>>;
}
```

The above change will make your example compile once you add lifetime parameters to all the `Elem`s, but it puts you in an awkward position when implementing `Elem`: you can't return a reference to `self`, so practically everything has to be `Boxed`.

It's hard to make a good recommendation given the vagueness of the example, but I suggest you take a step back and think about whether `BoxOrRef` is the right abstraction here. Fundamentally, you can't do anything with a `BoxOrRef` that you couldn't do with a reference, because the `BoxOrRef` might *be* a reference. At the same time, you can't do anything with it that you couldn't do with a `Box`, because it might be a `Box`. [`std::borrow::Cow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html) uses `ToOwned` to implement `Clone` and `into_owned` -- perhaps a similar approach could work for you. (And if you can, maybe just implement `ToOwned` for `dyn Elem` and use `Cow` directly.)